# start program using cmd

Tags: c++, file, cmd

I try to make a C++ program that opens some other programs(using cmd).The code:

```
int main(){
int i=0,t;
string progs[100];
fstream db("db.txt",ios::in);
while(getline(db,progs[i++])) {}


for(t=0;t<i-1;t++) {
    string open="start "+progs[t];
    system(open.c_str());
}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Program is located on desktop , and works well for all files.
The problem is that it can't open a program named KBot.exe(it says the program does not exist).
For example,I wrote in db.txt following:

```
patch.exe
KBot.exe
Shutdown + tasks.exe
```

All 3 are located on the desktop,but the program opens just the first and the last one.
And yes,the program name is correctly written.What causes it ?

Comment: And you can manually start this program from a command prompt?

Comment: You are trying to cheat in an online game, aren't you?

Answer (score 2):

- Your loop is wrong : `s/b (t=0;t<i;t++)`
- `patch.exe` and shutdown are probably in your `$PATH`, `KBot` is not.

Comment: my loop works just well.

Comment: run it by hand, you'll see that it's not correct